# First frame in rendered kdenlive project is mute, why?

Tags: mp4, kde-plasma, mlt

I have video in Kdenlive and I'm adding 2 guides which will be a place to cut my project:
http://www.netcreate.pl/kden1.png

This video isn't mute as you can see.
Next I render this parts using guides:

[netcreate.pl/kden1-2.png](http://netcreate.pl/kden1-2.png)

First and second. But after export first frames are mute and audio isn't synced. I have put exported videos at same time-line to show this problem:

http://www.netcreate.pl/kden3.png

I checked all settings and I can't find it.

How to export exact part with full, synced audio without mute at the beginning??

Sorry for inconvenience, I can't post images without bigger experience/reputation in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that what you are seeing is a result of the fact that compressed formats are difficult to seek accurately. I assume that your source clip is an mp4 or some similar compressed format. You may find that you have better luck if you operate on sources that are uncompressed.

It would be interesting to see the results if you started with a clip with PCM audio and exported the cut to the same format. I expect that the synchronization would be better. Note: I haven't tried your exact scenario this myself. But I have fought similar problems with KDENLIVE in the past. Personally, before I edit any clips in KDENLIVE, I transcode everything to .mov files with video encoded as dnxhd and audio encoded as pcm_s16le. Since doing this, I see much fewer problems with audio sync and seeking.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced it, and it appears to be a bug. It reproduces whether using a zone/guide selection in the render dialog; or simply trimming a clip, adding it to beginning of timeline and rendering entire project. Interestingly, I do not reproduce it using Shotcut 15.03 by encoding a trimmed clip or adding a trimmed clip to the timeline and encoding that. For all of my tests I was using PAL MPEG-2 clip rendering to DV. A patch to fix the bug is welcome.

Comment: Next, I tested with a very special uncompressed a/v sync test clip from Tektronix, and it does not reproduce the problem! Again, I output to raw DV to ensure very little room for error on the encoding output and subsequent decoding. (The raw DV format has a simple format that embeds the audio for each video frame along with the video frame.) This suggests there is a seeking problem in the avformat producer with some compressed formats.

Comment: Next, I converted the uncompressed test clip to H.264 MP4 with 2 B-frames. That clip reproduced the problem and showed the audio as shifted out-of-sync by one frame. I also tested that clip in Shotcut by encoding a simple trimmed clip, and now it reproduced the problem as well with the same shift.

Comment: you're right, than you! And also thank you for working on MLT that I've been using for few projects!

Comment: I opened a bug for this. I want to work on it soon.  https://github.com/mltframework/mlt/issues/69

Comment: Dan thank you. I've done additional tests and sometimes it cuts with additional 1 or 2 frames at the beginning or at the end. For mi it's unusable.
Can I provide for you additional screen shots and tests results to help?